# Global function is not working javascript window object

Tags: javascript

Below is some javscript code here:

```
showFullName(); // Peter Ally
window.showFullName(); // Peter Ally
```

These two function calls are on window object only but the first call works fine, but the second one gives the error below:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
var firstName = "Peter",
lastName = "Ally";

function showFullName () {
   console.log (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
}

var person = {
    firstName   :"Penelope",
    lastName    :"Barrymore",
    showFullName: function () {
       console.log (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }
};

showFullName (); // Peter Ally
window.showFullName(); // it should output: Peter Ally, but giving error 
person.showFullName (); // Penelope Barrymore
```

Comment: Where did you put this? Browser console, Node.js repl, jsfiddle, external script in html?

Comment: in  fiddlesalad.com/less/

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> showFullName(); // Peter Ally
> window.showFullName(); // Peter Ally
> ```
>
> These two function calls are on window object

No, only the second one is. The first one is in your local scope.

> but the first call works fine, but the second one gives an error

That means there is no `showFullName` method on `window`. You didn't execute your code in the global scope of a html page, but declared a local-scoped function. In whatever scope that is.